# using the ng change in angular 2 using ng model variable

Tags: angular

How can I use the ng-change event in angular 2? Whenever the ng-model variable is changed, a function has to be called.

```
[(ngModel)]="variable"
ngchange=variable;
```

Comment: whenever the value of the variable is changed i have to call the function to validate the variable\

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use the `ngModelChange` event:

```
[(ngModel)]="variable" (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)"
```

**Edit**

According to your comment, I think that you should use form control with a custom validator.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="variable" [ngFormControl]="ctrl"/>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.ctrl = new Control('', (control) => {
      // validate the value
    });

    this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      // called when the value is updated
    });

  }
}
```

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/

Comment: I have a related question,
Is there a way to reach the same functionality on Reactive form with setValue I set the value into an FormControl (represented a text input) than the user on the UI set a text value? I noticed ven I set a value via setValue it not affected the dirty flag.

Answer (score 11):

component have two-way binding

- `()` for output
- `[]` for input

that means you can use ==>`[value]="variable"`<== for showing data on html
and ==>`(input)="setVariable($event)"`<== to update your var in ts/js.

`event.target.value`

FYI==>https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Comment: you can also use TEMPLATE Variables instead of $event