# Angular: On value changes how to know if value set via UI or programatically

Tags: angular

In Angular I use the valueChanges observable to call a function when the value of a form control changes. As the docs say "A multicasting observable that emits an event every time the value of the control changes, in the UI or programmatically."

My question: is it possible to check if the value was changed programmatically or via UI (the view)?

The reason I want to check this is because there are actions that I want to do ALWAYS when the value has been changed to a particular value. E.g. when a setting in my application is turned off I also want to turn off a related setting. 
But there are actions I want to do ONLY when the value has been changed via the UI (in the view, by user action). E.g. send notification to API that setting has been enabled for analytics purposes

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867440/using-the-ng-change-in-angular-2-using-ng-model-variable). whats is your angular version?

Comment: You can call `control.setValue(vaule, { emitEvent: false });` to not fire `valueChanges`

Comment: Separate your concerns. Only use the forms for UI related changes, and use a service for application state changes. Don't mix the usage of forms with non-form related problems.

Comment: Angular version is 7.0.3. I'm using reactive forms. Not firing `valueChanges` is not an option because I do want part of the callback to be executed

Comment: @cgTag If I want to update the value of form control B when form control A changes, should I manipulate / update the form from the service? Both B and A can also be controlled in the UI, but B will only be shown when A is enabled

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you have tried. Explain what you wanted it to do. This question right now is kind of broad. So try to narrow it down to a specific coding example. Thanks